# Setting up OpenCV Java bindings on OS X

Tags: java, opencv, video-capture

I'm following the instructions here to set up OpenCV for Java development. http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html.
I'm using Mac OS X 10.10.1 with Java 1.8.0_25.

I can't get Java to be added to the "To be Built" list using cmake, which is a prerequisite for creating the Java-linked native libraries and jar files needed for Java development.

The warnings I get are as follows. I don't have a clue how to interpret this output and I don't understand if I need to respond to the warnings or not. There is no mention of Java in the errors. Can anybody help me get beyond this stage?

[NOTE: I have asked this on the OpenCV forum but didn't get a response.]

```
CMake Warning (dev) at apps/haartraining/CMakeLists.txt:37 (add_library): Policy CMP0038 is not set: Targets may not link directly to themselves. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0038" for policy details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Target "opencv_haartraining_engine" links to itself. This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at apps/haartraining/CMakeLists.txt:37 (add_library): Policy CMP0038 is not set: Targets may not link directly to themselves. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0038" for policy details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Target "opencv_haartraining_engine" links to itself. This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at apps/haartraining/CMakeLists.txt:37 (add_library): Policy CMP0038 is not set: Targets may not link directly to themselves. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0038" for policy details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Target "opencv_haartraining_engine" links to itself. This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at apps/haartraining/CMakeLists.txt:37 (add_library): Policy CMP0038 is not set: Targets may not link directly to themselves. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0038" for policy details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Target "opencv_haartraining_engine" links to itself. This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at apps/haartraining/CMakeLists.txt:37 (add_library): Policy CMP0038 is not set: Targets may not link directly to themselves. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0038" for policy details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Target "opencv_haartraining_engine" links to itself. This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at apps/haartraining/CMakeLists.txt:37 (add_library): Policy CMP0038 is not set: Targets may not link directly to themselves. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0038" for policy details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Target "opencv_haartraining_engine" links to itself. This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at apps/haartraining/CMakeLists.txt:37 (add_library): Policy CMP0038 is not set: Targets may not link directly to themselves. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0038" for policy details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Target "opencv_haartraining_engine" links to itself. This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at apps/haartraining/CMakeLists.txt:37 (add_library): Policy CMP0038 is not set: Targets may not link directly to themselves. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0038" for policy details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Target "opencv_haartraining_engine" links to itself. This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at apps/haartraining/CMakeLists.txt:37 (add_library): Policy CMP0038 is not set: Targets may not link directly to themselves. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0038" for policy details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Target "opencv_haartraining_engine" links to itself. This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at apps/haartraining/CMakeLists.txt:37 (add_library): Policy CMP0038 is not set: Targets may not link directly to themselves. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0038" for policy details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Target "opencv_haartraining_engine" links to itself. This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev): Policy CMP0042 is not set: MACOSX_RPATH is enabled by default. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0042" for policy details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

MACOSX_RPATH is not specified for the following targets:

opencv_python

This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing OpenCV with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). It saves you from a lot of trouble. After installing [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) it is as easy as typing in those two lines. (ffmpeg is optional, i needed it for video)

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv --with-ffmpeg --with-java
```

After that you just have to add the files this location:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/VERSION_NUMBER/share/OpenCV/java
```

to your project.

And don't forget to load the library in your code with:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```